# Convergence of empirical measures in Wasserstein distance

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, wasserstein-distance

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be iid random variables with common distribution $\gamma$, the standard Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb {R}$, and let
$\mu_n = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}$, $n \geq 1$, be the empirical measures based on the sample $X_1, X_2, \ldots$. Is there anything known on the rate of convergence of $E (W_p (\mu_n, \gamma))$ as $n \to \infty$, where $W_p$ is the Wassertein distance with exponent $p \geq 1$? Same question if the $X_i$'s are standard
Gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Answer (score 1):

A complete literature can be found in the article of Fournier and Guillin https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00440-014-0583-7

Comment: I was interested in the exact rates in this Gaussian example. Does this reference address this issue?

Comment: The rate in the one-dimensional case is different from the one holding in higher dimensions. For $\mathbb{R}$, I suggest to have a look at the book by Bobkov and Ledoux: One-dimensional empirical measures, order statistics, and Kantorovich transport distances.

Comment: Thank you, but there is nothing in higher dimension in the Bobkov-Ledoux Memoir?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The reason is simple, the situation in one dimension is relatively different from higher dimensional case. In one dimension a Bahadur representation type of theorem can be used whereas no such thing exists (yet) for $d \geq 2$. Bobkov and Ledoux decided to treat only the 1D case in their book.

Comment: There is recent progress on the exact rates for multidimensional Gaussians: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.07579